# How does " 一切" mean all/entire?

Tags: kanji

This word contains 一 "one" plus 切 "to cut" .. so how would this mean all/entire? ...
I searched before coming here and found something [https://kanjiportraits.wordpress.com/2016/10/23/the-kanji-刀切窃初分雰紛契喫潔-刀-sword-knife-to-cut/](https://kanjiportraits.wordpress.com/2016/10/23/the-kanji-%E5%88%80%E5%88%87%E7%AA%83%E5%88%9D%E5%88%86%E9%9B%B0%E7%B4%9B%E5%A5%91%E5%96%AB%E6%BD%94-%E5%88%80-sword-knife-to-cut/)
 .. they explained that as  " When there is nothing left as if it were a cut off, it meant “all.” "..
So is this explaination right? (I mean the explaintion in the site for why this kanji means "all")
 and if not then what the right explaination for why kanji 切 means "all"

Comment: Not sure this is all there is so, it'll be a comment, 一切 is a short version of he word 一切合切, which means entire, and I know that doesn't make much sense. Also some kanji words don't always match what the collection of the letters and the meaning of the word because they slapped what the sounds making the kanji make up than the meanings, this is called 当て字 and it does happen from time to time, like 多分, which there was the word たぶん and they just slapped on those kanji

Comment: Yes bro your example "たぶん " is right ..but this word which i asked about is not from this category ..it took it's meaning from the kanji 切 because as you see in the link this kanji the meaning "all" and has explaination for this ...and my question to kanji experts is this explaination right? and if not then what the right explaination for the meaning "all" of kanji 切